# Close screen when a value changes in Riverpod

Tags: flutter

How do I close a screen (call `Navigator.pop`) when a certain value changes?

I am using `riverpod` to watch for the values.

Comment: could you include some code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`WidgetRef.listen`](https://pub.dev/documentation//flutter_riverpod/latest/flutter_riverpod/WidgetRef/listen.html) to listen to state changes. From the docs:

> Listen to a provider and call listener whenever its value changes.
>
> This is useful for showing modals or **other imperative logic**.

The code is going to be something like this:

```dart
class MyHomePage extends ConsumerWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(context, ref) {
    ref.listen(theProvider, (previous, next) {
      if (isTheEnd(next)) {
        Navigator.of(context).pop();
      }
    });

    ...
```

Here's a complete example:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    const ProviderScope(
      child: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends ConsumerWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(context, ref) {
    ref.listen(counterProvider, (previous, next) {
      if (next % 2 == 0) {
        showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (_) => AlertDialog(
            title: Text('Value is even: $next'),
          ),
        );
      }
    });
    final counter = ref.watch(counterProvider);

    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            const Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => ref.read(counterProvider.notifier).increment(),
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}

final counterProvider = StateNotifierProvider<Counter, int>((ref) {
  return Counter();
});

class Counter extends StateNotifier<int> {
  Counter() : super(0);

  void increment() => state++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create some kind of Function that handle that. The function required a build context to get the Navigator and you could call the Navigator.of(context).pop or Navigator.pop(context) when you want.

```
onChangeValue(BuildContext context, dynamic value){
  if(value!=null){
  Navigator.of(context).pop();
  }
}
```